# Linux: check how much memory was allocated to a process using vmstat, free, of meminfo

Tags: linux, memory

How would I use either vmstat, free, or meminfo to see how much memory was allocated to a process? I also need to do the same for a process running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

vmstat, free and meminfo display the total usage of memory in the system, not only for one process, so I am afraid you can't use any of them. I would recommend to use pmap:

```
pmap <PID>
```

The last line displays the total memory usage by the process. Since also processes in the background have PID, you can check also them.

Comment: Okay, thank you. As someone who is new to Linux, how would i execute pmap without running the process in the background? Wouldn't running pmap stop the process?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "execute pmap without running the process in the background" - you simply type it into terminal. pmap shows you how much memory the process currently uses, it doesn't stop the process.